# Возможно ли запустить cordova проект,без оплаты Apple Develop Program на реальном устройстве с Xcode 7?

Tags: javascript, xcode, phonegap, cordova, ionic

Знаю, что возможность запускать свои проекты на swift прямо на реальном устойстве, появилась с приходом Xcode 7,поскольку и сам это прибывал.
Но вот с проектом на Cordova у меня произошла ошибка "build failed " ,хотя если запускать этот же проект в емуляторе, то все работает отлично.

Answer (score 1):

Можно еще использовать [PhoneGap Developer App](http://app.phonegap.com/).
Правда, если вы используете сторонние плагины, то это не сработает - нужно будет залезть [в код](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-developer) и пересобрать его.

Answer (score 0):

https://build.phonegap.com/

Только так. Без аккаунта не возможно.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?